# Execute a command after matching a specific rule of iptables

Tags: linux, bash, iptables, shell-script

Is it possible or is there any way from which a bash script can be executed using iptables?

Like I wanted to execute a bash script if incoming traffic on a udp port crosses 1000pps

I tried searching on web but couldn't get anything relevant

Comment: how do you currently monitor the traffic

Comment: @DeerSpotter I use nload.. But that shows the overall traffic of an interface

Comment: what is your os platform?

Comment: I am using LINUX OS